# How to SELECT * using multiple variables in MySQL with Node.js and Express?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Hello I am trying to do a request in node.js with MySQL that is similar to

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE tag="some_word" AND username="some_username"`

I have not been able to figure out how to make a request work when wanting to use more than one variable at once. I can get my requests to work when doing something like

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE username="some_username"`

but I can't seem to find any answers on how to do this when adding the AND to the query.  Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SELECT not working in node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434357/select-not-working-in-node-js)

Comment: @Roberrrt I'm sorry but I'm not sure how this is a possible duplicate of the post you are comparing it to. Can you explain why you think that it might be? It doesn't seem to me that he is asking the same question of how to use multiple variables in one request using SELECT.

Comment: I'm, not really sure why that URL appeared there, i'd swear that that was _not_ the URL I put there.
Either way, on to your question:
What have you tried, where is your code, do you have some sort of example?

Comment: @Roberrrt I found an answer. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well, my help, my help, Dylan helped you :). I'll upvote his answer, if you feel it answered your question, you should accept it by pressing the green icon on the left side ;).

Comment: @Roberrrt I accepted it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be something that you want. Just put whatever variables you want into the filter array and it will insert into the SELECT query.

```
var some_word;
var some_username;
var queryString = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE tag= ? AND username= ?;"
var filter = [some_word, some_username];

connection.query(queryString, filter, function(err, results) {
   //process results
});
```

More info at:
https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values

Comment: Thank you @Dylan this is what I was looking for!

Comment: @PaulB. Glad that it helps. Happy Coding :)